# Elasticsearch - Disable fuzzy search for numbers in string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to implement elasticsearch for searching products. Some product names contains numbers. I use fuzzy-search to make life easier for the users but I don't want the numbers to be fuzzy-searched. Can I disable fuzzy-search for numbers only but use it for the rest of the characters in a string?

Or is elasticsearch not fit for what I'm trying to achieve?

Example when searching for TV or monitors when I search for `Manufacturer TV 55"` I don't want `Manufacturer TV 65"` to show up in the results. Not in the top 10 at least.

Comment: Am also having same requirements now., not sure how to work it out

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @MariumMalik No I did not. I'm still interested in a solution but I'm not actively looking.

Comment: I am using PHP, so I separated the numbers and removed fuzziness from it. Did not find any solution from Elasticsearch side.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if search string is a number. In c#:

```
bool searchStringIsNumeric = int.TryParse(searchString, out int n);
```

In Elastic Search you could do something like this: (Using nest client here)

```
.Fuzziness(searchStringIsNumeric ? Fuzziness.EditDistance(0) : Fuzziness.AutoLength(4, 7))
```